# AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect Minimum Selection

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, minimum

I am new to AngularJS. What I am trying to do is to set a **minimum select limit** (which I just found max limit instead).

html code here..

```
<div id="table-tools-filtering"
        ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
        options="filterData"
        selected-model="filterModel"
        extra-settings="extraSettings"
        translation-texts="tableFilteringTexts"
        checkboxes="true"
        disabled="statusFilterDisabled">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to give more information. Are you using a directive? Or a library to show the multiselect? If so, give info about it.

Comment: I guess you are using this directive http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/ ? Unfortunately there is no minimum option but it is possible to validate the `filterModel` length yourself.

Comment: @ChristiaanScheermeijer Yes. I am using this. How can filterModel help setting the min length?

Comment: Well, for example, when you have a submit button add the following directive will achieve the same result: `ng-disabled="filterModel.length < 1"`

Answer (score 1):

if u having json data or array then u can manipulate and display options in selection

//js

```
$scope.abms = [];
     angular.forEach(news[0].NewsList, function (newsItems, index) {
         angular.forEach(newsItems.CategoryList, function (category, index) {
             $scope.abms.push(category.DisplayName);
          });
     });
```

u can refer this :  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cuvuzd8/2/)
I hope this will help

Comment: This is a good alternative! However this can't be applied in my case. But thanks anyway!! It helps me learn new thing :)